# Creating spring boot application with default package giving error why?

Tags: spring-boot

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestSpringBootApplication {
}
```

I have created spring boot application using default package It throwing the error.  Do we need to define in package?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add the error message, please?

Comment: > Task :bootJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
14:36:32: Tasks execution finished 'clean build'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I get error "Spring Boot Application in the default package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057553/why-i-get-error-spring-boot-application-in-the-default-package)