# Why I get error "Spring Boot Application in the default package"

Tags: java

I creaeted this class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootApplication {
}
```

on BootApplication I get the error:

```
Spring Boot Application in the default package
```

Any idea why I get the error above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your spring boot application in a package, default package is generally discouraged and should be avoided.

It can cause particular problems for spring boot applications that use @ComponentScan or @SpringBootApplication annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Did you kept this class in a package?

If not, please create a package, and keep the class inside it.

Also, put a main method in it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
}
```